# Android: Remove digits from string

Tags: android

I have a string with a format like `"integer1_text integer2"` (ex. "23_home 2" ).

I would like to remove the integer1, or replace it with an empty string (so keep only "home 2").

Integer1 is a number from 0 to 1000 and i just want to remove it.

I have tryed to do something like `string=mystring.replaceAll("[^0-9]+"_","");` but is not working correctly.

Any idea please?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are just a few small mistakes in your regex, try:

```
mystring.replaceAll("^[0-9]+_", "");
```

Comment: thanks mate,that works fine!All the answers are correct!thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use `indexOf("_");`

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the
>   specified character.

and use `substringIint startIndex, int endIndex);` to extract the String you need, with `startIndex` the index returned by `indexOf`

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
string.replaceAll( "\d+_(.*)", "$1" )
```